# create remote cache if does not exist during write and ignore remote cache if connection cannot be made

Tags: spring, caching, infinispan

We are using Spring Cache abstration and Infinispan server as a remote cache in front of a slow service.

I have two requirements:

- I would like to create the caches implicitly if they don't exist yet on the remote Infinispan server during access time based on a cache configuration template known by the Infinispan server.
- If the connection to the remote Infinispan server cannot be established I am ok to call the slow service behind it.

Could you suggest how could I implement this?

The built-in `@Cacheable` annotation does not have support for this.

Should I use a custom annotation with an Aspect? For the second requirement within the Aspect I could handle the connection issue to remote Infinispan server.

Answer (score 0):

Introduced this simple `CustomCacheable` annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomCacheable {

    // cache name
    String value() default "";
}
```

and with the following aspect I managed to fulfill both requirements:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class CustomCacheableAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomCacheableAspect.class);

    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    public CustomCacheableAspect(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.infinispandemo.custom.CustomCacheable)")
    public void customCacheablePointcut() {
    }

    @Around("customCacheablePointcut()")
    public Object allMethodCallsWithCustomCacheableAnnotationAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        CustomCacheable a = findCustomCacheableAnnotation(jp);
        String cacheName = a.value();
        Object key = getKey(jp);

        RemoteCache<Object, Object> remoteCache;
        try {
            remoteCache = getOrCreateCache(cacheManager, cacheName);
        } catch (TransportException e) {
            logger.warn("Cache `{}` connection error `{}`", cacheName, e.getMessage());
            return jp.proceed();
        }

        Object cacheValue = remoteCache.get(key);
        if (cacheValue == null) {
            logger.warn("Cache `{}` miss for key `{}`", cacheName, key);
            Object result = jp.proceed();
            remoteCache.put(key, result);
            return result;
        } else {
            return cacheValue;
        }
    }

    private RemoteCache<Object, Object> getOrCreateCache(CacheManager cacheManager, String cacheName) {
        return ((SpringRemoteCacheManager) cacheManager).getNativeCacheManager()
                .administration().getOrCreateCache(cacheName, "default");
    }

    private CustomCacheable findCustomCacheableAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        return AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(((MethodSignature) jp.getSignature()).getMethod(), CustomCacheable.class);
    }

    private Object getKey(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        return jp.getArgs()[0];
    }
}
```